# Nonexistence of a continuous injection from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$, for all $n \geq 2$.

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity, connectedness

I'm trying to do the following exercise from my lecture notes:

> There does not exist a continuous injection from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$, for all $n \geq 2$.

I don't really know where to start, but I think it helps that the exercise is marked as harder than the following exercises before it:

> - $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$ is connected, for all $n \geq 2$.
> - $\mathbb{R}^n$ is nonhomeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, for all $n \geq 2$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: The existence of a continuous injection $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is very different from an arbitrary injection.

Comment: Yes, right - I had only read the comment "There is such an injective function, but not a continuous one." This is standard, I was searching for it on MSE.

Comment: Let $f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Let $B = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \lVert x\rVert \leqslant 1\}$. Consider $f(B)$, and note that there are many paths in $B$ connecting any two given points.

Comment: A sledgehammer, but nonetheless illuminating, result would be the following - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain

Comment: Now [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116350/continuous-injective-map-f-mathbbr3-to-mathbbr) answers the question. The answer of Pete Clark is for all $n\ge 2$.

Comment: Given such a map $i:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, consider the connected space $i(\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{p\}) = i(\mathbb{R}^n)\setminus \{i(p)\}$.

Comment: @anomaly, that won't help unless you know that image of $ \mathbb{R}^n$ is open, which it actually is in this case.