# There is no continuous injective function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$

Tags: real-analysis

I have the following question, more general that [Continuous injective map $f:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116350/continuous-injective-map-f-mathbbr3-to-mathbbr)

Let $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a domain. If $f:U\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$  ($m< n$) is a continuous function, how to prove that $f$ is not injective.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Continuous injective map $f:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116350/continuous-injective-map-f-mathbbr3-to-mathbbr)

Comment: This is not true. Consider U equal to the nullset. Also consider U having lower vector-space dimension than n (thus its open sets are the null set).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really an application of a classical fact known as [Invariance of Domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain). Namely, take $g:U\to \mathbb{R}^{m}\times \mathbb{R}^{n-m}$, by $g(x)=(f(x), 0)$. Then $g$ is an injective continous function from $U\to \mathbb{R}^n$, so by invariance of domain has an open image. But $Im(g)=Im(f)\times \{0\}$, which cannot possibly be open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ while $n>m$. Thus we have a contradiction.

Comment: A continuous bijection is not necessarily a homeomorphism.

Comment: @Gaffney It is when your domain is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the range is $\mathbb{R}^m$. This is the content of the qouted theorem, "Invariance of Domain"

Comment: It may be a consequence, but as stated, it requires $n=m$.

Comment: The image on the linked wikipedia page seems to show a counter-example to what you're claiming.

Comment: @Gaffney As $m<n$ one can embed $\mathbb{R}^m$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ naturally.

Comment: @Sayantan $\mathbb R^m$ is not open in the topology of $\mathbb R^n$

Comment: Look, the question is about continuous injective maps from $\mathbb R^m\to\mathbb R^n$.  If $m<n$, such maps exists by space-filling curves.  Whatever argument you make needs to not apply to this case.  But this argument does.

Comment: @Gaffney The problem is for $f : U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ when $m < n$. One can view $f : U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ as a map $f : U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$. Then $f(U)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f$ is homeomorphism onto $f(U)$.

Comment: @Sayantan  What if $f(U)=\mathbb R^m$ ?  Then $f(U)$ is not open in $\mathbb R^n$.  Just like a line is not open in a plane.

Comment: @Gaffney That's the point. Such an $f$ cannot exist.

Comment: @Sayantan  Wait, you're assuming that such an $f$ cannot exists?

Comment: @Gaffney You are indeed right, I didn't read the wikipedia page, I learned this theorem from another source. The statement is if you have  $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and and injection $f:U\to \mathbb{R}^m$ for $m\le n$, then $f$ is a homeomorphism. Sayantan is right though that this is clearly implied by the quoted theorem, just take the map $g:U\to \mathbb{R}^m\times \mathbb{R}^{n-m}$ by $g(x)=(f(x), 0)$. Then your map is still an injection, so the theorem on wikipedia applies. This actually immediately implies the second part, so this actually makes the argument simpler, which I have done.

Comment: Makes sense; thanks.